# What is more efficient while working with PRBS generation: using arrays or structs for bit fields?

Tags: c

While doing scrambling and de-scrambling operations, what is a good way to store bit fields. Using every bit in an array of chars or struct with each bitfield as members. Can anyone explain it from hardware perspective.

Comment: struct vs. array shouldn't really matter, but using `int` (or, if you care about portability, something like `intfast32_t`) instead of `char` *may* be a win depending on architecture.

Comment: My favorite strategy in this case is unions.